# Does Azure REST APIs have OpenAPI specifications?

Tags: azure, api, rest, swagger, openapi

Does all the [Azure REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) have OpenAPI/swagger or similar endpoints?
(Click the table of contents in the link to see the full list.)

If so, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may not all return OpenAPI via an endpoint, but they are all documented here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs

Comment: Great answer. Especially their READMEs about autorest was a nice piece in the puzzle. Also this: "The next step in the process after a spec is completed is to generate SDKs and API reference documentation."

Comment: The swagger json defs are useful. You know of an example where they are being exposed through an endpoint?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't.